# xcode UICollection View opening another view controller

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller

I have a UICollectionViewController  and already shown images in a Cells, as i click/tap particular image, that 'pushes' to a normal ViewController. How do i do that? Here's the code I have so far...
want to open selected image in other view controller, please help

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [imagearray count];
}

-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier=@"Cell" ;
    customcell *cell=[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    [[cell nyimage]setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[imagearray objectAtIndex:indexPath.item]]];
    return cell;

}
```

Comment: you should implement `collectionView:didSelectItemAtIndexPath:` and set the delegate of the collection view.

Comment: do u knw how exactly it is implemented ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could implement the delegate method like this:

```
-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    DetailViewController* viewController = [[DetailViewController alloc] init];
    //configure detail view controller
    // viewController.detailInfo = ...
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: how can we achieve same kind of pop out animation in case of controller as image does in iphone photo gallery when image opened?

Comment: @BaSha to achieve this you need to use custom view controller transitions (iOS 7 only)